# DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS <SPName/TableName> is not working

Tags: sql-server

I have generated the stored procedure with SQL Server Management Studio 2016 v13.0.16. After generated script, I have executed the script and I'm getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF

The error occurs at line:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[SP_Test]
```

I have checked the SQL Server version:

```
select @@version
```

The result is:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64)   
Aug 15 2017 10:23:29   
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ).
```

Generated script as:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[SP_Test]
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Test]    Script Date: 02/24/2020 12:28:17 PM ******/
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[SP_Test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Test]    Script Date: 02/24/2020 12:28:17 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_Test]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test] AS'
END
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author: <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]
AS
BEGIN
select * from Emp
END
GO
```

Does anyone help me?

Comment: You are using `SQL Server 2012` not `2016`

Comment: I am using SQL server management studio 2016

Comment: `Management Studio` is the client tool not the `SQL Server database`. see `print @@version`

Comment: the version showing as SQL Server 2012.  problem with version  and i need to change

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF EXISTS` argument of `DROP PROCEDURE` statement is only available in SQL Server 2016 and newer.

> IF EXISTS
>   Applies to: SQL Server ( SQL Server 2016 (13.x) through current version).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You can use a 2 statement approach in earlier versions:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('dbo.SPName', 'P') IS NOT NULL) BEGIN
  DROP PROCEDURE dbo.SPName;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE sbo.SPName...
```

Comment: It is working fine. but, why did generate SQL server script as  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS [dbo].[SP_Test] ?

Comment: Because IF EXISTS is not a thing in SQL Server 2012

Comment: I am using the SSMS 2016. SQL server version showing as SQL 2012. How to change it?

Comment: SSMS is not SQL Server. SSMS is a client application, what matters is the SQL Server's version. Using a newer version of SSMS will not magically upgrade the SQL Server it is connecting to. The server will still have to understand the statement and SQL Server 2012 will not understand `IF EXISTS` regardless of the client application (SSMS in this case)

Comment: Thank, I will ask IT team in my office to change the SQL server 2016  from SQL server 2012

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Top 1 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[SP_Test]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    BEGIN

    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]

    END



    /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_Test]    Script Date: 02/24/2020 12:28:17 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SP_Test]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test] AS'
    END
    GO
    -- =============================================
    -- Author: <Author,,Name>
    -- Create date: <Create Date,,>
    -- Description: <Description,,>
    -- =============================================
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]
    AS
    BEGIN
    select * from Emp
    END
    GO
```

Simply u can check sp exists or not ...if exists then delete..using sysobjects..

this will work across all ther version of SQL Server

Comment: I know the above script woks fine. but the main problem  with my pc has SSMS 2016 and  SQL server 2012

Comment: IF EXISTS (SELECT Top 1 1 FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[SP_Test]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
    BEGIN

    DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Test]

    END

Comment: @@Raju Gaddam instead of select * from...u can use Top 1 1..it will make very faster...

Comment: @AkhileshSingh There is literally no performance difference between `TOP 1 1` and `SELECT *` in the context of `EXISTS`.

Comment: @@Pred...there is difference between while Top 1 1 and select *..... Top 1 1 will pick up only One column only..on the other hand select * will pick all the column and check.....so there is diffence in that...